# Symfony2 session is empty in another action

Tags: symfony, session

I have a bundle which uses php's native sessions so I am using this to handle it:

```
framework:
    session:
            storage_id: session.storage.php_bridge
            handler_id: ~
```

In my first action the session is working, I get the username provided in my php's native session. But once I change of Action, my session is empty.

I actually have this:

```
indexAction(){
        $phpCas->execute(); //my service with the php's native session
        $session = new Session();
        $session->start();
        $user = $session->get('username')['fullName'];//I successfully get my full name
}

anotherAction(){

        $session = new Session();
        $session->start();
        $array = $session->all();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array); //array is empty
        echo "</pre>";
}
```

I tried $session = $request->getSession(); but still empty.

Also tried $session->save();

and this:

```
framework:
    session:
            storage_id: session.storage.php_bridge
            handler_id: session.handler.native_file
            save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/sessions"
```

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT1:**
Thanks to the first answers it looks like that now:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $user = $session->get('user');
        if($user == null)
        {
            $phpCas = $this->container->get('phpcas');
            $phpCas->execute();
            $session = new Session();
            $session->start();
            $user = $session->get('username')['fullName'];
            $session->set('user', $user);
        }

public function createAction($persno, Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $array = $session->all();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array);
        echo "</pre>";
```

}

I still get an empty session in the second Action, I forgot to mention that I access to the second Action that way:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_platform_create', array(
                    'persno' => $persno,
                )));
```

May it be the problem?

**EDIT2:**
I am trying right now to do what the guy in the last post in saying:
http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=71389

But actually I can't make this working either.

Comment: is there a need of phpCas->exexute() in another function?

Comment: @asfandahmed1 No it should be used one time, it redirects to a login page of the university, once we are logged in, it stores in a php's native session the user (I believe it also stores things in cookies). My other Actions() should only check if there is an existing user with phpCas->getUsername(); if not, redirects to the homepage.

Comment: @Hewyn do you got the answer for this problem , i am facing the same issue

Comment: @HarshMiddha As far as I remember, the native session was using phpCAS to verify user authentication. There was a config file from phpCAS that needed to be modified in order to allow to read the session from another page than the main one. So in my case, the problem did not come from Symfony2.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to start the session, cause it is already autostarted by Symfony, also you should get the session from request ($session = $request->getSession()) or container ($session = $this->container->getSession()) inside your controllers

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

indexAction(Request $request){
        $phpCas->execute(); //my service with the php's native session
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $user = $session->get('username')['fullName'];//I successfully get my full name
}

anotherAction(Request $request){
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $array = $session->all();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array); //array is empty
        echo "</pre>";
}
```

**Update to you edits:**

createAction($persno, Request $request) - wrong

createAction(Request $request, $persno) - right

And you should not to put request directly in redirect, it is inserted automaticly by Symfony as 1st param

Comment: Ok I am using request->getSession() and it still works for my index but my array is still empty in my anotherAction(). Could it be because I use a redirect and I don't specify $request as parameter in it?

Comment: Thanks for your update, I removed $request and tried to invert the params order but it is still not working. When I do $session->all(); there is nothing inside.